# UIEdgeInsets not working

Tags: ios

I want the button text to appear near the middle of the button, in the x-dimension. Yet the button text still remains on the far left of the view, as if `x` were `0`. I've made sure to `setTitleEdgeInsets` and `setContentHorizontalAlignment`. I also tried setting the `contentEdgeInsets` instead of the `titleEdgeInsets`. What have I missed?

```
UIButton *row = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:
                 CGRectMake(0, index * kRowHeight, 320, kRowHeight)];
[row setTitle:value forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
[row setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
[row setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(180.0, 20.0, 0, 0)];
[self.view addSubview:row];
```

Answer (score 2):

I ordered the parameters incorrectly.

`UIEdgeInsets` are defined as

```
typedef struct {
   CGFloat top, left, bottom, right;
} UIEdgeInsets;
```

Comment: You had me wondering if that was the issue, but you didn't say what the "fixed distance" was.

Answer (score 1):

The button has a `titleLabel` property. Change text alignment on it.

Comment: I don't want the button title to be centered, I want it to be offset at a fixed distance from the left.

Comment: Uicontrol is yor friend then

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with edgeInsets 20 20 20 20 ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi add this code for Inset Button

```
extension UIButton {
    /**
        Creates an edge inset for a button
        :param: top CGFLoat
        :param: left CGFLoat
        :param: bottom CGFLoat
        :param: right CGFLoat
    */
    func setInset(#top: CGFloat, left: CGFloat, bottom: CGFloat, right: CGFloat) {
           self.titleEdgeInsets =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)
    }
}
```